# Google Cloud GKE Node Pool Metrics instance_group/size == <node-pool-max-size>

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, monitoring, alarm, signalfx

I am using SignalFX to create an alert via metrics from a Google Cloud GKE cluster.
I want to be able to trigger an alert when number-of-nodes-in-node-pool == node-pool-max-size.
I am not using GCP autoscaling under the k8s cluster as the cluster is managing the node pool itself.
I can use metric "instance_group/size" to get the current number of nodes in the node group but cannot find a metric to get node-pool-max-size (I cannot use an autoscaler metric as autoscaler is not being used).
Can anyone point me to a metric or combination of metrics that can be used here?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute) currently there is no metric to monitor the node pool maximum size. The metric you are using  **Instance_group/size** is the only metric to monitor the current number of nodes and maximum size of node pool.