# Get max_node_count in GKE Node Pool with Cloud monitoring API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-kubernetes-engine

Problem: I cant get max_node_count from Google cloud monitoring API with stackdriver exporter in GKE.

I use GKE (created by terraform) with  cloud monitoring and my own prometheus in cluster. For monitoring count of nodes i want to take count form API. Now i can get only current size of nodes in node pool with

```
compute.googleapis.com/instance_group
```

but it's compute engine level, so it hasnt got kubernetes node pool autoscaler. In GKE cloud monitoring i havent seen anything about node pool and cluster autoscaler T_T

Question: How can i get max_node_count of node pool in GKE with API?
Example from TF in google_container_node_pool and i need to get 9 number.

```
  autoscaling {
    min_node_count = "2"
    max_node_count = "9"
  }
```

P.S. I found such [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68315203/google-cloud-gke-node-pool-metrics-instance-group-size-node-pool-max-size?rq=2) but i dont believe that im first who want to monitor count of max nodes of cluster